# Efficient algorithms to determine the roots of: $p(x) = r^x $ in the finite field $GF(q)$, where $r$ a primitive root of the field

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, exponential-polynomials

I need to make sure that no efficient (i.e., polynomial time) algorithm exists for the following problem:

**Exponentiating Polynomial Root Problem (EPRP)**

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with $\deg(p) \geq 0$ with coefficients drawn from a finite field $GF(q)$ with $q$ prime, and $r$ a primitive root for that field. Determine the solutions of:
$$p(x) = r^x $$
where $x\in\{0,\dots,q-1\}$.

Note that, when $\deg(p)=0$ (the polynomial is a constant), this problem reverts to the Discrete Logarithm Problem, which is believed to be NP-Intermediate, i.e. it is in NP but neither in P nor NP-complete.

To the best of my knowledge, efficient (polynomial) algorithms to solve this problem  do not exist (Berlekamp and Cantor–Zassenhaus algorithms require exponential time to solve this particular problem, see below). Finding roots to such equation can be done in two ways:

- Try all possible items $x$ in the field, and check whether they
  satisfy the equation or not. Clearly, this requires exponential time in the bitsize of the field
  modulus;
- The exponential $r^x$ can be rewritten in polynomial form, by using
  Lagrange interpolation to interpolate the points
  $\{(0,r^0),(1,r^1),\ldots,({q-1},r^{q-1})\}$, determining a
  polynomial $f(x)$. This polynomial is *identical* to $r^{x}$ precisely because we are working on a finite field. Then, the difference $p(x) - f(x)$, can be
  factored in order to find the roots of the given equation (using
  Berlekamp or Cantor–Zassenhaus algorithms) and the roots read off the factors. However, this approach is
  even worse than exhaustive search: since, on average, a polynomial
  passing by $n$ given points will have $n$ non-null coefficients, even
  only the input to Lagrange interpolation will require exponential
  space in the field bit size.

Does anyone know if this problem can be solved efficiently by using a different approach and algorithms ? A reference will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this similar question ? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145620/complexity-of-a-problem-remotely-related-to-the-discrete-logarithm-a-x-gx

Comment: @Aurel, I looked at the question you suggested, but it appears to be unrelated to the problem I am asking here.

Comment: are you sure? If $q$ is prime, what about taking $x_1$ to be a root of $p(x)-1$ and choosing $x$ congruent to $x_1$ mod $q$ and congruent to $0$ mod $q-1$ with CRT ?

Comment: and by the way the Cantor–Zassenhaus algorithm runs in expected polynomial time.

Comment: Actually what is $x$ in your problem ? Your sentence "Try all possible items x in the field" makes it look like you are thinking about $x\in\mathbb{F}_q$ but then $r^x$ does not make sense.

Comment: @Aurel, I think you you are trying to solve a different problem, something that could be stated as $p(y) = r^x$, but, instead, I need to solve $p(x) = r^x$ for $x \in GF(q)$. Why do you think that in this case $r^x$ does not make sense ($r$ is a primitive root of $GF(q)$) ?

Comment: One more thing, you are probably missing the point that, even though the Cantor–Zassenhaus algorithm complexity is polynomial,  its input is exponential in the field bitsize, so the computational complexity is exponential. Think about the factorization of a composite number $n$ for instance. Trial division (the simplest algorithm) requires only $\sqrt n$ operations, so you would say that it's complexity is polynomial, but it's not (no polynomial algorithm has been discovered for factorization as you already know). You must think carefully about the input bit size.

Comment: What is your definition of $r^x$ when $x$ is in $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $r$ is a primitive root in $\mathbb{F}_q$ ?

Comment: It's simply exponentiating $r$ to $x$.

Comment: @MassimoCafaro: Do you assume $q$ to be prime and identify the elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ with the integers $0, 1, \dots, q-1$?

Comment: @j.p.: yes, $q$ is prime and the elements of $GF(q)$ are the integers $0,1,…,q−1$

Comment: @MassimoCafaro: Oh, $q$ is prime. Ok, then it makes sense, but with your definition $r^{x+y}\neq r^xr^y$ in general, is that what you mean? You should specify the statement of your question more precisely, this is very confusing.

Comment: @Aurel, this is what I mean. I though it was clear from the beginning that $q$ is prime, since the finite field is a Galois Field. Then, the fact that in general $r^{x+y} \neq r^x r^y$ is a natural implication I guess, but please correct (and forgive) me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MassimoCafaro: There is a Galois field with $q$ elements for each $q$ that is a *power* of a prime, so it was not clear. When you write "a finite field $GF(q)$" with no more precision, most people will think that $q$ can be a nontrivial power of a prime. And when you write $r^x$ with no more precision, most people will think you mean something satisfying $r^{x+y}=r^xr^y$.

Comment: crossposted: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/complexity-class-of-this-problem

Answer (score 1):

This question is not posed well. Let $F={\mathbb F}_q$ where $q$ is a prime-power.
A polynomial $f\in F[x]$ gives rise to a function $\phi(f)\colon F\to F$ via evaluation. Moreover, 
$\phi\colon F[x]\to F^F\colon f\mapsto\phi(f)$ is an epimorphism onto the ring $F^F$ of all functions $F\to F$. Indeed, $F[x]/(x^q-x)\cong F^F$. Thus your exponential function $p(x)=r^x$ is *equivalent* to a polynomial function $f(x)$ of degree at most $q-1$. [Edit: Using Noam Elkies comment below, $\deg(f)$ is exactly $q-1$.] It seems to me that you should just replace the function $p(x)$ with the equivalent polynomial $f(x)$, and considering the difference
$p(x)-f(x)$ is unhelpful.

Factoring a degree $n$ polynomial over ${\mathbb F}_q$ using the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm has complexity ${\rm O}^{\sim}(n^2\log q)$. Since $n=\deg(f)= q-1$, factorization algorithms will not give you a polynomial in the input size $\log q$.

Comment: But the input size is $O(\log q)$, not $O(q)$.
Exhaustion over the $q$ possible $x$ already gives an
$\tilde O(q)$ algorithm, so $O(q^2 \log q)$ doesn't help.

Comment: @Noam There are $\phi(q-1)$ choices for the primitive element $r$. Could it be that the smallest value of $\deg(f)$, as $r$ varies, is ${\rm O}(\log q)$?

Comment: Sorry, it can't even be smaller than $q-1$:
the polynomial $f(x+1)-rf(x)$ has degree $\deg \, f$ and
and $q-1$ roots (all $x \neq -1$).

Comment: @Glasby, why the primitive roots are only $\phi(q)$ instead of $\phi(\phi(q))$ ?

Comment: @Massimo A cyclic group of order $q-1$, such as the multiplicative group ${\mathbb F}_q\setminus\{0\}$, has $\phi(q-1)$ generators. Note that $\phi(\phi(q))=\phi(q-1)$ when $q$ is prime.

Comment: @Glasby, thank you, of course you are right. Lesson learned: never ask a question late at night, when sleepy and out of control ;-)

Comment: @Glasby, $p(x) = r^x$ is not an exponential function, it's an equation in which $p(x)$ is a polynomial. Alternatively, I want to find the zeros of $p(x) - r^x = 0$. Anyway, I am glad that no other possible approach (besides exhaustive search and polynomial factorization) seems to exist (since I want to use this problem to build a cryptographic protocol, I must be sure it requires exponential time) and I am awarding you the bounty. Thanks to all of the people involved in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

For an argument of why this probably doesn't have an easy solution, note that for *every* value $a$ such that $p(a) \neq 0$, the discrete log problem and the Chinese remainder theorem together show there exists a unique $b \in \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots, q(q-1) - 1 \}$ such that $b \equiv a \pmod{q}$ and $p(b) = r^b$.

So the problem isn't "does this have any roots", but "does this have any *small* roots", which is pretty hard to deal with.